# shell script - check mongod server is running

Tags: mongodb, shell

I have a shell script to do some mongo db actions:

e.g. `mongo testdb --eval "db.dropDatabase()"`

BUT, if the mongod server is not running, I get:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.4
connecting to: testdb
Tue May 14 04:33:58 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js:84
```

Is there a way in mongo I can check the connection status? Eventually I want something like:

```
if(mongod is running):
    mongo testdb --eval "db.dropDatabase()"
else:
    echo "pls make sure your mongod is running"
    exit 1
```

Comment: One simple way: you could check `%errorlevel%` in Windows or bash `$?` to see if the mongo command returned an error code.

Comment: @WiredPrairie in bash.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should be able to create a bash script like this:

```
mongo --eval "db.stats()"  # do a simple harmless command of some sort

RESULT=$?   # returns 0 if mongo eval succeeds

if [ $RESULT -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "mongodb not running"
    exit 1
else
    echo "mongodb running!"
fi
```

Comment: This script fails if you set bind_ip and port

Comment: Hi, How do I check whether mongodb is running is running in an auth mode using shell script and capture the error code .

Comment: This script is good even today. If you are using auth, create a X.509 user with a simple "read" role.

Answer (score 4):

try running this in your shell script:-

> pgrep mongod

If the value is numeric you know that the process is running, if you get an empty value, flag it as service not running...

Answer (score 1):

this is what i run to check if mongod is up:

```
# this script checks if the mongod is running.
# if not, send mail
#

EMAILIST=dba@wherever



`ps -A | grep -q '[m]ongod'`

if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
    exit 0
else
    echo "The mongod server SB2MDB01 is DOWN" | mailx \
    -s "Server DOWN: SB2MDB01" $EMAILIST
fi

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have administrative rights, you could also do a `sudo systemctl status mongod` which gives you lots of helpful additional information:

```
mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-03-14 09:26:53 UTC; 5 weeks 9 days ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
 Main PID: 420 (mongod)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mongod.service
           └─420 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```